# Creating a dynamic table In HTML and AngularJS from contents of a Javascript array

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table

I need help creating a dynamic table in the format of a round robin competition using HTML and AngularJS. An array of strings will be given and then the table will be created based on how many names were in the list so part of the table will be generated dynamically and part of the table will always be the same. This is an example of a table that would be generated if I passed an array with 8 names. Only columns A, B, and C should have any information when the table is generated though I kept everything blank for simplicity's sake. The rest of the boxes should all be text input fields.

Until now most of the tables I have done have been pretty simple and I am a little out of my depth here, any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have a full 8 teams this would get you started

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>club</th>
    <th>team</th>
    <th>#</th>
    <th ng-repeat="item in items">{{$index+1}}</th>
    <th>V</th>
    <th>TS</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{item.club}}</td>
    <td>{{item.team}}</td>
    <td>{{item.rank}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{black:$index==$parent.$index}"></td>
    <td><input ng-model="item.v"></td>
    <td><input ng-model="item.ts"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FPSzooPiISwPgiOr9l6O?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: This was very helpful however the snippet

ng-class="{black:$index==$parent.$index}"

does not shade the boxes black like I would expect, in fact it does not appear to do anything. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: works fine in my demo doesn't it? You have to use a css rule for that class

Comment: it was a formatting error when copied in, thanks for the help!

Comment: should consider accepting an answer sometime if they helped you

Answer (score 0):

This is a really nice example of using nested `ng-repeat` elements.

Please see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2OGYn3onX8KoSkcRA1uL) for a working demo.

The main trick for detecting when to black out a box is to use `ng-init="$rowIndex=$index"` on the outer `ng-repeat` (where we generate a row for each entry).  This allows the inner `ng-repeat` (where we generate a column for each entry) to have an `ng-class="{'blackout': $index==$rowIndex}"`